# Jquery Ajax Call is not working in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have searched many solution but nothing worked. I am doing just a simple `Ajax` call using Jquery in `Visual studio 2019` but my code is not hitting `Ajax` call. Here is my code

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    
    function GetDataDetails() {            
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetData",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",               
            success: function (response) {
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                var Records = xml.find("Table");
                if (Records.length > 0) {
                    alert(Records.length);
                }
            },                
            error: function (d) {
                alert(d.responseText);
            }
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        $("[id*=Button1]").bind("click", function () {
            GetDataDetails();
            return false;
        });            
    });
</script>
```

c# code

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetData()
        {
            using (SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                using (SqlConnection Con = Connections.Create())
                {
                    Cmd.Connection = Con;
                    Cmd.CommandText = "GetColumnList_pro".Trim();
                    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Option", "GetColumnList".Trim());
                    using (SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        using (DataSet Ds = new DataSet())
                        {
                            Con.Open();
                            Adp.SelectCommand = Cmd;
                            Adp.Fill(Ds);
                            return Ds.GetXml();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I used breakpoint on `Chrome` and check that it's hitting `GetDataDetails` Method but when It reach to first line `$.ajax({` it out from method.
There is no error when I debug my code. It's hitting the method also but out from here `$.ajax({`.
What am I missing?

Comment: The web method: `GetData` is not hit? Or the `GetDataDetails` JS method not hit?

Comment: It's hitting `GetDataDetails` but out when it reach to `$.ajax({`

Comment: I tried, but nothing happened.

Comment: Perhaps remove the `data: '{}'` as your web method didn't expect to receive any request body. Also maybe you can check the DevTools > Network to see whether the request is sent. And place a breakpoint in your web method to see it hit.

Comment: I check, but it's not hitting `$.ajax({`

Comment: @Krampus I updated.

Comment: I agree with Krampus - that jQuery version is very old and has security issues within it that have been addressed in the newest versions for example.

Comment: Why are you trimming a hard coded strings that have no space? Example: `"GetColumnList".Trim()` seems odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the button markup.
(so, this is a question about some button click code not working, but the all-important markup for the button is missing).

I don't suggest you write code to attach some click event to a button. You are in most cases far better off to simply enter the click function to run in the button's markup.

Introduction of a jQuery selector in place of some simple markup introduces more failure points in your code. Worse yet, now in place of looking at the button markup, you ALSO now have to look everywhere else in the markup for some possible jQuery button selector code that adds a click event. This not only increases developer workloads, but introduces more code of which it can fail.
(thus, developer workloads and debugging efforts are increased).

Looking at your jQuery selector code, you are using "*", when in fact for jQuery you are use "^" to ignore the starting text (so ^="ends with"), and you use "$" to select by starting with.

So, just dump that extra jQuery selector code.

So, we have a button, and markup like this:

```
        <input id="Button11" type="button" value="ajax test"
            onclick="TestFun();return false"
            />

        <script>

            function TestFun() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AJPostTest.aspx/Hello",
                    data: {},
                    success: function (response) {

                        alert('return value = ' + response.d)
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        // Handle the error response
                        console.log(error, status, xhr);
                    }
                });
            }

        </script>
```

And server method is this:

```
    [WebMethod] 
    public static string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello from server";
    }
```

Before you run above, hit f11 to open the browser debug tools.

Now, when I click above, the console shows this error:

[image]

Ok, that means I don't have the "$", and that means I do NOT have jQuery setup.

Let’s add jquery to the page:

So, we now have this:

```
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

        <input id="Button11" type="button" value="ajax test"
            onclick="TestFun();return false"
            />

        <script>

            function TestFun() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AJPostTest.aspx/Hello",
                    data: {},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {

                        alert('return value = ' + response.d)
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        // Handle the error response
                        console.log(error, status, xhr);
                    }
                });
            }

        </script>
```

And now the result is this:

[image]

So, fix your jQuery selector, or in fact REMOVE it, and test with a simple button as per above. (or post your existing button markup).

Also, if introducing the above sample test code into your existing page does not work?
Then as noted, check the browser debug tools, make sure jQuery is working.

Next up:

If your site has friendly URLs enabled, then in most cases, you need to edit/change the redirect mode to off.

Hence, check your site, and under app_start, open up RouteConfig.cs, and change this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;   <--- this to off
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
```